# white thumbnail for uploaded video in android app

Tags: android, video, slim

I am making api's for my android app using Slim framework.But when i upload video to local server from my android app by calling api,it generates white thumbnail for video in my app.How can i get the thumbnail for the uploaded video.

My code for making api is:

```php
$app->post('/do_upload', 'authentication', function () use ($app) {
    verifyRequiredParams(array('albumId'));
    global $user_id;

    $response = array();
    $file_path = "../uploads/$user_id/photo_gallery/thumbnails/";

    if (!file_exists($file_path)) {
        mkdir($file_path, 0777, true);
    }
    $thumbnail = $user_id . "/photo_gallery/thumbnails/";
    $response = array();

    if (isset($_FILES["files"])) {
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES['files']['name']);
        $detectedType = $_FILES["files"]["name"];
        $filetype = substr($detectedType, strpos($detectedType, ".") + 1);
        $newfilename = 'shared_' . rand(1, 99999) . '.' . end($temp);
        $file_path = $file_path . basename($newfilename);
        $thumbnail = "$user_id/photo_gallery/thumbnails/" . $newfilename;
        $filename = "$user_id/photo_gallery/thumbnails/" . $newfilename;
        $mobile_thumbnail = "$user_id/photo_gallery/thumbnails/" . $newfilename;

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        }

        $albumId = urldecode($app->request->post('albumId'));
        $caption = urldecode($app->request->post('caption'));

        $db = new DbHandler();
        if (($filetype == "gif")
            || ($filetype == "png")
            || ($filetype == "jpeg")
            || ($filetype == "jpg")
            || ($filetype == "JPEG")
            || ($filetype == "PNG")
            || ($filetype == "GIF")
            || ($filetype == "JPG")
        ) {
            $type = "image";
            $result = $db->SharedImage($albumId, $user_id, $caption, $filename, $thumbnail, $mobile_thumbnail, $type);
        } else {
            $type = "video";
            $result = $db->SharedImage($albumId, $user_id, $caption, $filename, $thumbnail, $mobile_thumbnail, $type);

        }
        if ($result != "null") {
            while ($res = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $response = array();

                $response["id"] = $res["id"];
                $response["event_id"] = $res["event_id"];
                $response["album_id"] = $res["album_id"];
                $response["status"] = $res["status"];
                $response["filename"] = $res["filename"];
                $response["contributedby_id"] = $res["contributedby_id"];
                $response["guest_id"] = $res["guest_id"];
                $response["thumbnail"] = $res["thumbnail"];
                $response["mobile_thumbnail"] = $res["mobile_thumbnail"];
                $response["order_id"] = $res["order_id"];
                $response["created"] = $res["created"];
                $response["updated"] = $res["updated"];
                $response["title"] = $res["title"];
                $response["type"] = $res["type"];
                $response["caption"] = $res["caption"];
                $response["taken"] = $res["taken"];
                $response["copied_from"] = $res["copied_from"];
                $response["media_size"] = $res["media_size"];
                $response["thumbnail_size"] = $res["thumbnail_size"];
                echoRespnse(200, $response);
            }
        } else {
            $response["message"] = "response contain no data";
            echoRespnse(200, $response["message"]);
        }
    } else {
        $response ["error"] = true;
        $response ["message"] = "Please select a file to upload";
        echoRespnse(200, $response);
    }
});
```

Please tell me why the thumbnail of video uploded is white and how can i get the video cover.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but where is the code that generates your thumbnail image?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31623754/create-video-thumbnail-in-slim?noredirect=1#comment51195936_31623754   .This is the code i am using to generate thumbnail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ffmpeg ,My problem was solved.Here is the code `exec('ffmpeg -y -i '.$file_path.'  -vcodec mjpeg  -ss 00:00:01  -vframes 1 -an -s 620x440 -f rawvideo '.$image.'',$thumb_stdout, $retval);`

This created a thumbnail at path $image of size 620*440.