# Create Video thumbnail in slim

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am creating api's using slim framework.My problem is that i am trying to upload video to localserver but the thumbnails of video are not generating.
I have tried ffmpeg but it is not working:

Here is my code:

```
exec('ffmpeg -itsoffset -4 -i C:\xampp\htdocs\givemethatpic\shared_17008.mp4  -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -ss 620x440  C:\xampp\htdocs\givemethatpic\tdrrsss.jpg');
```

I used ffmpeg-win32 setup and it installed the ffmpeg to C:\Program Files (x86).
I do not know where i am wrong.Please tell why thumbnail is not generating??

Comment: Do what everyone else does - check your inputs and outputs, enable debug/verbose output, run the command outside PHP, read the ffmpeg docs.

Comment: After searching alot i edited my code and now ffmpeg is genearting balck images now using this code @Synchro

Comment: Please help why this code is generating blank video thumbnails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the command like this `exec('ffmpeg -y -i '.$file_path.'  -vcodec mjpeg  -ss 00:00:01  -vframes 1 -an -s 620x440 -f rawvideo '.$image.'',$thumb_stdout, $retval);`
and everthing is working fine